# Homework Help(Bit manipulation)

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I am fairly new to bit manipulation so if you could help me that would be great!I understand what (&,|, ~ , ^) do when you compare two different bytes. I also understand that (<<) is like multiply by 2^i bit and (>>) is like dividing by 2^i bit. I have attempted this but I am think there is a better way to do it.

Here's the question:

Write a function that sets a certain number of bits in an integer to 1 and all the other bits to 0. The value should be returned from the function. For example, when integers x = 3 and y = 8 are passed to the function, the function should return the integer that has a binary number of 00000000 00000000 00000111 11111000. That is, convert bits from the 3rd to 11th (3+8) to 1 and others to 0.
Hint: This function has two parameters: a starting bit number and the number of bits counted from the starting bit. Bitwise addtion and shift should be used.

Here's what I have so far:

```
int function(int startBit, int numBits){
   int num = 0;
   int num1 = 1;
   int i;

   for(i = startBit; i < startBit+numBits; i++){
          num = num | num1 << i;

   }
   return num;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is a little slow but fits the requirements:

```
// First, create the number of 1 bits needed
int result = 0;
for (i = 0; i < numBits; ++i)
  result = (result << 1) + 1;

// Then shift the 1 bits to the correct position
result <<= startBit;
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual bit twiddle for this is:

```
((1 << numBits) - 1) << startBit
```

but I'm not sure that satisfies your "Bitwise addtion and shift should be used" restriction.

Comment: when (1 << numBits) > INT_MAX it the value will wrap.  The OP's example is 64bit, so this will only work if numBits < 32 (or on an ILP64: numbits < 64). Other than that this is a wonderful simplification.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely must pay attention to data types and the values of numBits and startBit or you will end up with the wrong results. There are many of these types of bit twiddles and they are often used in the context of hardware control registers where the values of numBits and startBit are constants and whose values are such that the result is well defined.